# Is it possible to detect screen recording in X11

Tags: arch-linux, x11, xorg, screenshot

On my mac, I used to have a programme called MicroSnitch which would notify me if an application was using the camera or the microphone with a little icon.

I'm using arch, with X11, and I was wondering if something similar was possible, but to reliably detect if another application (e.g. Zoom, Firefox) is capturing the screen (whether screenshots, recordings, etc.).

I have no idea how screen capturing works, but am assuming an application has to ask X11 for the output. Is that incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, screen recording on Xorg works by directly reading from the shared memory of Xorg where it keeps the graphic bitmaps. Hence, there is no (easy) way of tracking which application is reading the screen contents.